# Public resources, spark & conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, spark-view-engine

Using [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/15/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) to generate my resources. Problem is, spark dies when tries to generate dynamic views because there is app_globalresources.dll and myapp.dll somewhere there - deep into temp jungles.

> .spark(9,36): error CS0433: The type 'Resources.Account' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webpac\031ff06d\e6932d30\assembly\dl3\f31cd083\982c5673_7f8dca01\myApp.DLL' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webpac\031ff06d\e6932d30\App_GlobalResources.cwbnqwjg.dll'

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding? Your project seems to use previously generated App_GlobalResources.cwbnqwjg.dll.

Comment: Thought the same. But problem was my stupidity - as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved resource files from `App_GlobalResources` to simple folder `Resources` and it's cool.

Comment: I just fixed my own problem thanks to this!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263981/why-am-i-getting-app-globalresources-assembly-generated-error-cs0433