# Why am I getting App_GlobalResources assembly generated? (Error = CS0433)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, resx, app-globalresources

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC2 project, for which I have configured the localisation as follows ...

---

I have a separate Resources assembly, containing all my resx files. The settings for each resx file are...

```
Build Action             = Embedded Resource
Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy
Custom Tool              = PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace    = Resources
```

I have a tool which exports the strings from a database into the resx files and calls the resgen.exe tool to recreate the designer.cs file.

---

This all worked great, even when I changed the language settings of my browser and refreshed the page. It would pick up the correct strings.

That was in a temporary working folder (I use subversion). I've now moved to working in my normal folder and am getting a rather odd error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The
>   type 'Resources.XXXX' exists in
>   both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\6c657d01\aaca70ae\assembly\dl3\a36dac65\78c87110_3724cb01\Resources.DLL'
>   and
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\6c657d01\aaca70ae\App_GlobalResources.g6fehiio.dll'

I have deleted all of my temporary asp.net files, re-run the web app and it regenerates both of the above mentioned assemblies. The really odd thing is that this all worked before I moved to my usual working folder.

So, can anyone tell me what is generating this App_GlobalResources assembly, which I don't need or want, because all my resources are contained in the Resources assembly I've created.

PS - The reason I went with Resources.dll was to get around a problem I was having with generating the resources using my database extract tool. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230585/run-custom-tool-for-resx-files-in-mvc2-project-from-an-external-application-sc))

PPS - I am using VS2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doh!

I think when I switched my "usual working folder" to the branch this was in, I had some files in a "App_GlobalResources" folder.

I just tried to create a new App_GlobalResources folder in VS2010 and it told me there was already one there, but it wasn't in the solution explorer.

I looked in windows explorer a number of times and just didn't see that folder.

Anyway, problem solved!

moral: don't trust solution explorer or svn switch to delete files that don't belong in the working copy :'(

Comment: I second that.  Found the folder in the bin directory even though it was removed from solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know how to stop App_GlobalResources automatically generationg assemblies in Temporary ASP.NET files. I did figure out how to get rid of those annoying warnings.

As the warning says:

`Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'Resources.XXXX' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6c657d01\aaca70ae\assembly\dl3\a36dac65\78c87110_3724cb01\Resources.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6c657d01\aaca70ae\App_GlobalResources.g6fehiio.dll'`

The type **Resources.XXXX** exists in both assemblies. Change your `Custom Tool Namespace` to be something other than "Resources" and these warnings will dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the .resx to another folder (not App_GlobalResources)
2. Keep the Custom Tool Namespace set to 'Resources'