# Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'Resources.labels' exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

I just upgraded my blog (http://jeffcren.com) to BlogEngine 1.6.1 (from 1.6.0) in order to use the reCaptcha extension.  I upgraded my local code from 1.6.0 to 1.6.1, then published via FTP through WebMatrix.  After the upgrade, I am getting this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: 
The type 'Resources.labels' exists in both
'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9fd92f87\45a2ba06\assembly\dl3\a64307f6\f14811b8_0291cb01\App_GlobalResources.DLL' 
and 
'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9fd92f87\45a2ba06\App_GlobalResources.md7pit6m.dll'
```

The source file and line number where it breaks varies, but it is always the same basic message.  What differs is the "md7pt66m" section of the App_GlobalResources.md7pit6m.dll (the second file path in the error message).

I was able to fix the error locally by deleting the Temporary ASP.NET Files, but I can't do this on my hosting server (GoDaddy). Is there something I can do to fix the error?

Based on suggestions from the codeplex discussion page, I have edited web.config file in order to cycle the app pool, and renamed BlogEngine.Core.dll to BlogEngine.Core2.dll and then back in order to restart the blog. I have also added batch="false" to the `<compilation>` tag in web.config (based on [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/11/public-hotfix-patch-available-for-asp-net-compilation-issues.aspx)).

I have turned custom errors off, so you can see the error on my site now.

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me: Set the namespace of the Resources to the namespace of the web project.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete Global.asax files from Bin folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know exactly what caused the problem, but I deleted all files from the server, then downloaded a clean BlogEngine 1.6.1 web project from CodePlex.  I modified web.config to use my SqlServer db, and uploaded everything again. This time it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this issue.

[Public resources, spark & conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002372/public-resources-spark-conflict)

Try give your App_GlobalResources another namespace like Resources and move it into Resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just deleted bin folders sub files manually and updated resource files (I put a comma sign to sentences), then it worked.

I don't know what the real problem is, but it seems that it is about cache and you have to delete the existing cache.